# What does "going on nine" mean?

Tags: word-usage

I heard a native speaker say

> I built an eight-figure company going on nine and I don't neccesarily think I've ever worked hard.

What does "going on nine" mean?

Comment: You haven't heard *The Sound of Music*? ("I am sixteen going on seventeen; you are seventeen going on eighteen")

Comment: Oh, got it. I knew "go on" is used in that sense sometimes. But just failed to think of that. By the way, do native speakers use "go on" in that sense very commnonly? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does “22 going on 16” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33085/what-does-22-going-on-16-mean) The basic expression, as well as the clever tweaks, is addressed.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin Ashworth. I think my question has basically been answered.

Comment: The collocation 'going on' is a set phrase for 'nearly'. It is not productive, ie 'go on' or 'goes on' does not share this meaning at all. It's just 'going on'.

Comment: Thanks, Mitch. I've got further undertanding about "going on" through your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Non-native speakers may not find this easily, thinking it is based on verbal "going". However:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/going-on)
>
> going on:
> adverb, preposition
>
> informal (UK also going on for):
> nearly or almost (a particular number, age, time, or amount):
> *It was going on midnight when we left the party.
>
> There were going on 200 people at their wedding.*

The use of 8 in relation to "figure" directs the reader to the idea of value rather than age. Had age been the topic of interest, it would have read "... 8 years going on 9".

So 8 going on 9 means that the present worth of the company is tens of millions (8 digits; e.g. $85,000,00), but it is nearly hundreds of millions (9 digits; e.g. $120,000,000).

Comment: Thanks for more explanation.  I wonder what if one wants to express the meaning that the company is going soon to be nine years old,  can "going on" be used anyway?

Comment: I wonder why can't "going on nine" in my question interpreted as the company going to be nine years old. Could anybody please help me out?

Comment: *I am eight going on nine* implies age. But once I say eight-figure, I refer to valuation alone. So eight-figure company going on nine refers to figures.

Comment: I have edited the answer to deal with the (unlikely) possibility of years of age rather than value.

Comment: Thanks, Anton. You've explained pretty clearly.

Comment: Welcome to the site. The question was closed because it led to a duplication in a previous answer. Like many such closures, there was an aspect (in this case quite small - the years/value ambiguity) that was **not** dealt with by the duplicate answer. However, do not be discouraged by this; it is just one of the quirks of the site. Come again.